# Issue with yield in nested workflow

Tags: f#, either, computation-expression

I'm trying to write my own Either builder as part of my quest to learn computation expressions in f#, but I have hit a wall with what I think is issue with Combine method. My code so far:

```
type Result<'a> = 
    | Failure
    | Success of 'a

type EitherBuilder() = 
    member this.Bind(m,f) = 
        match m with
        | Failure -> Failure
        | Success(x) -> f x
    member this.Yield x =
        Success(x)
    member this.YieldFrom x = 
        x
    member this.Combine(a,b) = 
        match a with 
        | Success(_) -> a
        | Failure -> b()
    member this.Delay y = 
        fun () -> y()
    member this.Run(func) = 
        func()
```

With this code I test the Combine with two tests:

```
let either = new EitherBuilder()
...
testCase "returns success from 3 yields" <|
    fun _ -> 
        let value = either {
            yield! Failure 
            yield 4
            yield! Failure
            }
        value |> should equal (Success(4))
testCase "returns success with nested workflows" <|
    fun _ -> 
        let value = either {
            let! x = either { 
                yield! Failure 
                } 
            yield 5
            }
        value |> should equal (Success(5))
```

The first test passes, as I would expect, but the second test fails with following message:

> Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' in
>   nunit.framework.dll either tests/returns success with nested workflows:
>   Failed:    Expected: `<Success 5>`   But was:  `<Failure>`

I don't get it. The `x` is not yielded, so why does it influence my parent workflow? If I move let! below yield the test passes. I'm staring at my Combine implementation and it looks for me that for `Failure*Success` pair the actual order of arguments would not influence the result, but yet it seems like it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do!` and `let!` clauses within the expression get desugared to `Bind` calls. This means that your `Bind` is called when you do `let! x = ...`.

More specifically, your second example gets desugared into the following:

```
let value = 
    either.Bind(
       either.YieldFrom Failure,   // yield! Failure
       fun x ->                    // let! x =
           either.Yield 5          // yield 5
    )
```

So it never even gets to `yield 5` - the computation stops at `let! x =`.

In order for the inner computation to "never become part" of the outer one, just use `let` (without the bang):

```
let value = either {
     let x = either { 
         yield! Failure 
         } 
     yield 5
     }
```

This will correctly return `Success 5`.

Comment: I completely missed this consequence of let!, thanks :)